# Возможно применить паттер State в реализации CRUD функций?

Tags: c#, .net, шаблоны-проектирования

Консольное приложение. Есть меню при старте, но на мой взгляд всё выглядит непрвильно. Возможно применить паттерн "State" в данном случае ? Можно так избавиться от switch case ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
DataFunction dataFunction = new DataFunction();
dataFunction.InputMenu();
}

public void InputMenu()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Add Customer? --- 1, Remove customer? --- 2, Show 
    All Customer? --- 3");
    string _value = Console.ReadLine();

    switch (_value)
    {
        case "1":
            AddCustomer();
            break;
        case "2":
            RemoveCustomer();
            break;
        case "3":
            ShowAllCustomers();
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("You clicked an unknown letter");
            break;
    }

public void AddCustomer()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Input Name");
    string _name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Input Adress");
    string _adress = Console.ReadLine();

    _dataContext.Customers.Add(
        new Customer
        {
            Name = _name,
            Adress = _adress
        });
    _dataContext.SaveChanges();

    InputMenu();
}
```

Comment: Паттерн state нужен когда в **нескольких** местах приходится использовать if/switch из-за разного **внутреннего** состояния.

Comment: Может быть, вопрос не именно про то, можно ли применить pattern состояние, а про усовершенствование кода, то есть code-review. [Здесь сказали, что можно использовать метку "Инспекция кода"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8113/185885).

Comment: Кстати, может быть что-то такое можно. Если говорить приблизительно, то думаю, что pattern состояния позволяет описать систему, которая переходит из одного состояния в другое, которой соответствует граф состояний. Тут такая ситуация присутствует для меню. Допустим, можно сделать `Enum` возможных состояний и по какой-нибудь команде, например, `SetMenuState(stateEnum)`, переходить на нужное действие (причем, чтобы метод перехода между такими состояниями в конце вызывал `SetMenuState(StateEnum.Default))`. Но, лично мне бы больше понравился другой подход (в следующем комментарии):

Comment: Например, в desktop-ном приложении иногда делают диалог-сервис, то есть, пользователю показывается диалог, а в коде это выглядит, как вызов метода сервиса, который возвращает объект/параметр, (данные пользователя). Если так, то в данном случае, можно было бы выделить код запросов в отдельные методы (возможно, статические, какого-то отдельного класса). Тогда бы можно было отделаться одним циклом, внутри которого switch и вызовы запросов на ответ пользователя. Хотя, виноват: одно другому не мешает, и не всегда можно циклом отделаться, где-то может понадобиться граф состояний. Тогда еще задумка:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше вместо state [паттерн visitor](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Может быть, видоизменить код из википедии можно примерно так, как в написано в комментариях

```
internal interface IVisitor    //вместо этого CRUD
{
    void Visit(Point2D p);     //вместо этого Add(AddWrapper x)
    void Visit(Point3D p);     //вместо этого Remove(RemoveWrapper x)
    //...
}
```

```
internal class Point3D : Point   // обертка над конкретной операцией
    // internal class AddWrapper: WrapperBase
{
    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z)   // здесь не конструктор, а метод ввода пользователя с вызовами Console.Read(..)
    {
        X = x;  
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public double X { get; }   // здесь данные введенные пользователем
    public double Y { get; }
    public double Z { get; }

    public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        //сначала вызов метода ввода пользователя

        visitor.Visit(this);     //visitor.Add(this);

        // метод (со switch-ем) можно сделать статическим в базовом классе-аналоге Point - WrapperBase
        // и вызвать его тут
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, (но без паттерна state), вкратце, если выделить получение input-а от пользователя в отдельные статические методы (возможно, сделать специальные классы ValueObject-ы для input-а), а так же выделить и CRUD в отдельные статические методы, то можно использовать такой класс:

```
public interface IUserAction
{
    void Launch();
}

public class UserAction<TUserAction>: IUserAction
{
    public Func<TUserAction> GetInput { get;set; } 
    public Action<TUserAction> DoAction { get;set; }
    public IUserAction Next { get;set; }

    public void Launch()
    {
        //проверки на null, возможно, return

        DoAction(GetInput());
        Next?.Invoke(); 
    }
}
```

Для UserAction-а выбора операции TUserAction будет int, а next будет null, а в DoAction будет switch. В остальных случаях next будет вот этим про который только что написал, и везде вместо Func-ов и Action-ов (кроме одного Action-а) подставляются актуальные статические методы.